# Analyzing crashdump, wrong symbols

Tags: iis, windbg, crash-dumps

I am having trouble analyzing a crashdump with windbg. I run:

```
.sympath SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
.reload /f /i
```

To get the symbols. All symbols seem to have downloaded to c:\symbols and then i run:

```
analyze -v
```

To analyze. But i get "WRONG_SYMBOLS" in my result (se below). I run windbg in the same computer that the dumpfile is from (Windows Server 2008 64bit). Why don't my symbols load correctly?

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+0
000007ff`00be314a 4c8be0          mov     r12,rax

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000777530e5 (ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionTable+0x0000000000000035)
   ExceptionCode: c00000fd (Stack overflow)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 000000001d535fa8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

USER_LCID_STR:  ENU

OS_SKU:  7

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000001d535fa8

RECURRING_STACK: From frames 0x34 to 0x34

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  w3wp.exe

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_STACK_OVERFLOW

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to 0000000000000000

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`1d535fb0 00000000`777531d1 : 00000000`1d536148 00000000`1d5360c8 00000000`1d536080 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionTable+0x35
00000000`1d536040 000007fe`eb806d6b : 00000000`1d536748 00000000`1d538160 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionEntry+0x31
00000000`1d536070 000007fe`eb806bd9 : 00000000`1d536df0 00000000`1d538810 00000000`1d5380b8 000007fe`eb806e5d : clr!LazyMachState::unwindLazyState+0x12b
00000000`1d536700 000007fe`eb805d45 : 00000000`1d536a30 000007fe`00000000 00000000`1d5368f8 000007fe`eb986c5c : clr!HelperMethodFrame::GetFunction+0xd4
00000000`1d5367e0 000007fe`eb80609c : ffffffff`fffffffe 000007fe`eb750000 000007fe`eb750000 000007fe`e3966de8 : clr!StackFrameIterator::ProcessCurrentFrame+0x8ae
00000000`1d5368f0 000007fe`eb80638b : 00000000`1d537fa8 00000000`1d5abee0 00000000`1d5abff0 00000000`1d536a30 : clr!StackFrameIterator::NextRaw+0x35c
00000000`1d536980 000007fe`eb8064a1 : 00000000`000000dc 000007fe`eb8054e9 00000000`00000000 00000000`1d536a30 : clr!StackFrameIterator::Filter+0x1a4
00000000`1d5369c0 000007fe`eb805c96 : 00000000`1d5372a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 000007fe`eb986c5c : clr!StackFrameIterator::Init+0xe6
00000000`1d536a00 000007fe`eb80534e : 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`000000d7 000007fe`e3966de8 : clr!Thread::StackWalkFramesEx+0x76
00000000`1d536da0 000007fe`eb8221b7 : 000007fe`ebdcefc0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`02758050 : clr!Thread::StackWalkFrames+0xb1
00000000`1d537eb0 000007fe`e38a10f6 : 00000000`02876970 00000000`12733d80 00000000`1d5382a0 000007fe`00000001 : clr!SecurityStackWalk::CheckNReturnSO+0x2b7
00000000`1d538240 000007fe`e38a109e : 00000000`03412510 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`02b31358 : mscorlib_ni+0x3810f6
00000000`1d538280 000007fe`e391d327 : 00000000`02b31358 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`01a2bb60 : mscorlib_ni+0x38109e
00000000`1d5382c0 000007fe`e391d219 : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`0000001c 00000000`00000000 00000000`0275dfd8 : mscorlib_ni+0x3fd327
00000000`1d538340 000007fe`e3efa480 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e38b058f 00000000`02b314e8 00000000`032dcd50 : mscorlib_ni+0x3fd219
00000000`1d538380 000007fe`e3f11e1f : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e3f11f5b 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x9da480
00000000`1d5383c0 000007fe`eb8090b4 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`0275dfd8 00000000`03411588 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x9f1e1f
00000000`1d538410 000007fe`eb8091c9 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`1d538470 000007fe`eb809245 : 00000000`1d538588 00000000`00000003 00000000`1d5385a0 00000000`1d538908 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`1d5384f0 000007fe`eb809718 : 00000000`1d5388f0 000007fe`e3f11f30 00000000`1d538800 00000000`00000001 : clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`1d538730 000007fe`ebc6928a : 00000000`1b9313e0 00000000`1d538870 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x44
00000000`1d538770 000007fe`ebcd62e0 : 000007ff`00f256a8 000007fe`ebddd180 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`1d538e60 : clr!SecurityStackWalk::ReflectionTargetDemand+0xca
00000000`1d538930 000007fe`eb7b7972 : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`00f256a8 000007ff`00d7cd10 000007fe`00000000 : clr!AccessCheckOptions::DemandMemberAccess+0xa1
00000000`1d538a00 000007fe`eb7b7a91 : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`0062ab28 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1d539040 : clr!ClassLoader::CheckAccess+0x132
00000000`1d538ac0 000007fe`eb7c4193 : 000007ff`0062ab28 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00d7cd10 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccess+0x111
00000000`1d538bb0 000007fe`eb7b7b1a : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1d538e10 00000000`00000001 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x226
00000000`1d538c60 000007fe`eb7b7a91 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ebfc0010 00000000`000000be : clr!ClassLoader::CheckAccess+0x3b
00000000`1d538d20 000007fe`eb7bf438 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`00000000 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00ee9278 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccess+0x111
00000000`1d538e10 000007fe`eb7bf1bf : 000007ff`00f265b8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 000007ff`00f256a8 : clr!CEEInfo::GetFieldInfoHelper+0x238
00000000`1d538ed0 000007fe`f1c87e44 : 00000000`1d5397f0 00000000`04000005 00000000`013303b8 000007ff`00f265b9 : clr!CEEInfo::getFieldInfo+0xcf
00000000`1d538f80 000007fe`f1be8937 : 00000000`00000074 00000000`0000000d 00000000`04000005 00000000`00000074 : clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyFieldAccess+0x110
00000000`1d539110 000007fe`f1be8cc7 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f1c875dc 00000000`00000001 00000000`1d5398e4 : clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper+0x1157
00000000`1d539640 000007fe`f1bd22c7 : 00000000`1d5397f0 00000000`01340190 00000000`00000001 00000000`01308cb8 : clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x197
00000000`1d5396f0 000007fe`f1bd15c6 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 000007fe`00000009 00000000`013303a8 : clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x1d7
00000000`1d539780 000007fe`f1bd2cae : 00000000`01a79780 00000000`1d879c20 000007fe`ebe47890 00000000`1bada2f0 : clrjit!THX_dop2+0x2c9
00000000`1d5399c0 000007fe`eb7c9853 : 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`eb75d0ed : clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0xba
00000000`1d539a40 000007fe`eb7c9783 : 00000000`01aa18a0 00000000`1d539cf0 00000000`1d539e30 00000000`00800000 : clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0xa7
00000000`1d539ad0 000007fe`eb7c96ba : 00000000`00800000 00000000`1d539cc0 00000000`1d539cf0 000007fe`eb757f75 : clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x63
00000000`1d539b30 000007fe`eb7c94b4 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`1d539cf0 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00800000 : clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46
00000000`1d539bc0 000007fe`eb829944 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x270
00000000`1d53a190 000007fe`eb7b70a6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`1d53a4a8 000007ff`00f256a8 : clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable+0xe4
00000000`1d53a220 000007fe`eb829c1c : 00000000`00000010 00000000`1d53a3d0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xb4ef3
00000000`1d53a320 000007fe`eb7c9455 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`1d53a460 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`0062ab28 : clr!GetCompileFlagsIfGenericInstantiation+0x83
00000000`1d53a360 000007fe`eb7f0741 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000000 : clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x211
00000000`1d53a930 000007fe`eb7f04b8 : 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000001 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1baf0f00 : clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x1dd
00000000`1d53aaa0 000007fe`ebced34c : 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`03410dd0 00000000`00000000 : clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x522
00000000`1d53abb0 000007fe`e417d9b9 : 00000000`03411568 00000000`027f9db0 00000000`03410c88 00000000`0340d350 : clr!MethodDesc::CompileMethod+0xfc
00000000`1d53ad50 000007fe`e2dcd0ba : 00000000`03410678 00000000`03410a50 00000000`02abddc0 000007fe`eb7890f2 : mscorlib_ni+0xc5d9b9
00000000`1d53ada0 000007ff`009576f2 : 00000000`03410228 00000000`034101d8 00000000`0340daa8 00000000`0340e420 : System_Core_ni+0x2ad0ba
00000000`1d53adf0 000007ff`0095759c : 000007ff`00d043b0 00000000`02a8a240 00000000`0340e420 000007fe`e2dc3b7a : 0x000007ff`009576f2
00000000`1d53ae40 000007ff`00be315f : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`0095759c
00000000`1d53ae80 000007ff`00be314a : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be315f
00000000`1d53aef0 000007ff`00be314a : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`0340e058 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be314a
00000000`1d53af60 000007ff`00be2fa3 : 00000000`02efe748 000007ff`00c572f8 00000000`0340e058 00000000`0340de40 : 0x000007ff`00be314a
00000000`1d53afd0 000007ff`00be2e7b : 000007fe`e2e4c578 000007fe`eb7890d0 000007ff`009a7620 000007ff`009a63b0 : 0x000007ff`00be2fa3
00000000`1d53b040 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340e420 00000000`03410138 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be2e7b
00000000`1d53b080 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`03410138 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340e480 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b0d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340e5d8 00000000`0340e480 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b130 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340e5d8 00000000`034100d8 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b180 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`034100d8 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340ef90 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b1d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340f100 00000000`0340ef90 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b230 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340f100 00000000`03410078 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b280 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`03410078 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340f5b0 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b2d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340f708 00000000`0340f5b0 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b330 000007ff`0095626a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0340f100 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e2dc0eb4 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b380 000007ff`0095614a : 00000000`0340e5f8 00000000`00000000 00000000`0303b008 00000000`00000000 : 0x000007ff`0095626a
00000000`1d53b3f0 000007ff`009560aa : 000007ff`009a4cd8 000007fe`e2e35c18 00000000`00000001 000007ff`00ee8908 : 0x000007ff`0095614a
00000000`1d53b450 000007fe`e2fcc15f : 00000000`0340f708 000007ff`00ee8908 00000000`0340f120 00000000`0303b008 : 0x000007ff`009560aa
00000000`1d53b480 000007ff`00d411c9 : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0340e8b8 00000000`0340e618 00000000`0340d4d8 : System_Core_ni+0x4ac15f
00000000`1d53b4e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033f3398 00000000`033f30f8 00000000`033f1fb8 : 0x000007ff`00d411c9
00000000`1d53b560 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033d7ea0 00000000`033d7c00 00000000`033d6ac0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b5e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033bc980 00000000`033bc6e0 00000000`033bb5a0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b660 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033a1488 00000000`033a11e8 00000000`033a00a8 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b6e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03385f68 00000000`03385cc8 00000000`03384b88 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b760 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0336aa70 00000000`0336a7d0 00000000`03369690 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b7e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0334f550 00000000`0334f2b0 00000000`0334e170 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b860 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03333f40 00000000`03333ca0 00000000`03332b60 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b8e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03318a20 00000000`03318780 00000000`03317640 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b960 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`032fd528 00000000`032fd288 00000000`032fc148 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b9e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`032d7108 00000000`032d6e68 00000000`032d58f0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53ba60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03617568 00000000`036172c8 00000000`03616188 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bae0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035fc048 00000000`035fbda8 00000000`035fac68 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bb60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035e0b50 00000000`035e08b0 00000000`035df770 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bbe0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035c5630 00000000`035c5390 00000000`035c4250 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bc60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035aa138 00000000`035a9e98 00000000`035a8d58 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bce0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0358ec18 00000000`0358e978 00000000`0358b2f0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bd60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03573720 00000000`03573480 00000000`0356fdf8 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: w3wp

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  49e03238

STACK_COMMAND:  ~16s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c00000fd_w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_STACK_OVERFLOW_w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/7_0_6002_18005/49e03238/ntdll_dll/6_0_6002_18541/4ec3e855/c00000fd/000330e5.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: Did you try setting the symbol file path to the path of your dump?

Comment: @Rockstart No... it is set to: SRV*d:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
do you mean that it should be set it to:
SRV*d:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA272.tmp
because that does not work...

Comment: Is this managed code? If so, you can get useful stack traces from the metadata alone.

Comment: By setting symbol path to the MS symbol server, you get the windows symbols, but not symbols from your own app. Those .pdb you must take care of yourself, and adding their path-

Take a lm to see which  .dll’s that not have symbols.

Also take a !teb too see the upper and lower limits for the stack.

Comment: Ok, i have my symbols to now:
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\MySymbols
If i do an ld i see that my dlls are marked (defered) and w3wp is marked (pdb symbols). I have all our .dll and .pdb files in that folder. Is defered good or bad...?

Comment: Read about "Deferred Symbol Loading" in WinDbg help. do a .reload /f to instant load the symbols before checking with lm. Then you are ready fo an !analyze -v   Have you checked the stack boundaries with !teb ?

Answer (score 1):

Your driver is the `clr`? The symbols are correct for this driver. Some OS symbols seem to missing but you probably don't need them. It seems that you're getting stack overflow (look at the beginning of the debug output) - and it sounds reasonable, the stack is very long.